# Spring JPA Transaction not available in servlet context but in Web-App

Tags: spring, hibernate, servlets, jpa, transactions

we have a Vaadin-based Web-Application which has the following architecture:

1. A Core-Module which uses JPA-Repositories and Services to deal with persistence.
2. We have a Vaadin-Web-App which uses the Core-Module and delegates all the persistence stuff to the core module. Transactions and stuff works there. You can in the logs that inserts are carried out and the data ends up in the database.
3. There is a servlet which is only there to offer endpoint so some other applications which send sometimes data to this servlet. The servlet then uses the services from the Core-Module to persist the data. But somehow the data ends NEVER up on the database. If you do a JPA-Save you can only see "Select" - Statements in the log.

I've did some research and somehow there is something wrong with the transaction - management. Which I do not really understand because the transaction management works in the regular web - app.

The application-context.xml of the Vaadin - Web-App:

```
<import resource="classpath:applicationContextCore.xml" />

<context:component-scan base-package="de.dmsb.my.configuration"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="de.dmsb.my.controller"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="de.dmsb.my.dto.xml"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="de.dmsb.my.handler"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="de.dmsb.my.services"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="de.dmsb.my.ui"/>
```

And here is the dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="de.dmsb.my.controller" use-default-filters="false" >
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

The endpoints are registered and I can send them data.

But when ever I try to persist the data using a service or repository from the Core-Module I see only select - statements in the log.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance,

Frank

UPDATE:

I changed the applicationContext.xml to the following but the problem still persists:

```
<import resource="classpath:applicationContextCore.xml" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="de.dmsb.my.configuration"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="de.dmsb.my.controller"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="de.dmsb.my.dto.xml"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="de.dmsb.my.handler"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="de.dmsb.my.services"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="de.dmsb.my.ui"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Comment: The `<tx:annotation-driven />` should be in the root context not the one of the servlet. As the latter will only enable transactions for that specific servlet only and only when there is a class in that same context which has `@Transactional` and generally your controllers shouldn't be driving the transactional boundaries.

Comment: Don't add xml, code as comments, improve/update your question instead!

Comment: Then your services aren't transactional I would say or there is something else wrong in your app which you aren't showing. Also why are you duplication the scanning for the `de.dmsb.my.controller` package, that leads to duplication.

Comment: I will remove the double scanning of the de.dmsb.my.controll package. The problem is, that I "inherited" this code.

Comment: The interesting thing is that it the inserts work in the Vaadin-Application. So the applicationContext.xml seems to work. The problem seems to be with the Dispatcher-Servlet.xml e.g. the Servlet Context.